Oracle BPEL 12c how to pull CSF-Key to BPEL composite and populate in soap header and send it to backend
I am using Oracle BPEL 12c I have created a CSF-MAP and CSF-KEY which contains a username and password my requirement is i have pull this CSF-KEY and add it in composite file and send it to the backend by placing this in the SOAP header.
Let's consider the backend Name is "BACK-END-IN"
I have attached "oracle/wss_username_token_client_policy" policy to the BACK-END-IN
and using the EDIT option I have over-riden the value with the CSF-KEY and CSF-MAP names but still the values are not populating  in the soap header.
Many thanks for considering my request.
